# ssrs iif statement for decimal places on a chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

Can anyone please help me with this iif statement.

I have a ssrs report with charts on it, deployed on sharepoint for the whole department to use.

My problem is with the decimal places.

Chart is designed to show values in millions as most of the values are in millions but problems arise when a salesman whose business is under a million runs the report. They see multiple zeros!

When I changed the number settings to allow 1 decimal places, the other sales guy doesnt want to see a decimal at the end of their values on the chart.

How do I write a IIF statement that will allow decimal places when values is less than 1 and no decimal when values are over 1.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression in your series label:

```
=IIf(Fields!Business.Value >= 1, FormatCurrency(Fields!Business.Value, 0), FormatCurrency(Fields!Business.Value, 1))
```